# Apache Airflow: How to template Volumes in DockerOperator using Jinja Templating

Tags: jinja2, airflow

**I want to convey list of volumes into DockerOperator using Jinja template:**

- hard coded volumes works fine:

  volumes=['first:/dest', 'second:/sec_destination']
- however following jinja template does not work:

  volumes=[f"{{{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='my_task', key='dockerVolumes')
  }}}}"]
  500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("invalid mode:
  /sec_destination')")

**I found workaround that is acceptable for me however is not perfect:**

- acceptable only for cases where volues would have always 2 elements

  volumes=[f"{{{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='my_task', key='dockerVolumes')[0] }}}}", f"{{{{ ti.xcom_pull(task_ids='my_task', key='dockerVolumes')[1] }}}}"]

Answer (score 1):

### For anyone who is using airflow >= 2.0.0

`volumes` parameter was deprecated in favor of `mounts` which is a list of `docker.types.Mount`. Fortunately, airflow evaluates templates recursively, which means that every object with `template_parameters` that is a value of any field in `template_fields` of the parent object will be evaluated as well. So in order to evaluate `docker.types.Mount` fields we need to do two things:

- Add `mounts` to `DockerOperator.template_fields`
- Add `template_fields = (<field_name_1>, ..., <field_name_n>)` to every `docker.types.Mount`.

So to template `source`, `target`, and `type` parameters in the `DockerOperator` subclass you can implement it the following way:

```py
class DockerOperatorExtended(DockerOperator):
    template_fields = (*DockerOperator.template_fields, 'mounts')

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        mounts = kwargs.get('mounts', [])
        for mount in mounts:
            mount.template_fields = ('Source', 'Target', 'Type')
        kwargs['mounts'] = mounts
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to provide a value of a field by template, that field must be part of **template_fields**.
[docker operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.9/_modules/airflow/operators/docker_operator.html#DockerOperator) does not have volume as template_fields that is why you cannot set it via jinja2.

The solution for this is to extend DockerOperator and include volume as template_fields.

Comment: actually my solution already have it: we have class that extends DockerOperator and includes:
   template_fields = ( 'volumes')
so it might be something else

Comment: What is type of dockerVolumes? It looks like a collection to me. If it is a list, can you please try removing [] from volume value?

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is writing your own ninja filter (for spliting pulled string from xcom) and add it as elem of 'user_defined_filters' in DAG object initialization.